# Can't get logout to work in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

I have tried every way imaginable.  Disabled SSO in Glassfish.  Put session.invalidate() in a jsp page and redirected.  Did a request.invalidate in a jsf backing bean.  What should I do?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

This works.

```
   private String email;

public ViewLines() {


}

@PostConstruct
public void onLoad() {

    Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
    email = principal.getName();

    if (email != null) {
        User user = userService.findUserbyEmail(email);

        for (Acl acl : user.getAclList()) {

            if (acl.getAccess().equals("allow")) {
                digPackageLines(acl.getTreeId());
            }
        }
    } else {
        FacesUtils.addFatalMessage("Couldn't find user information from login!");
    }
}  


 @WebServlet(value = "/j_security_logout")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsf");
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that it didn't work? Aren't you just using browser back button and/or viewing a page from browser cache?

Comment: Hey Balus.  I was able to get it working.  I forgot to update this thread.  I think the problem was I was accessing the Principal in a session bean as a private member of that session bean.  I changed the Principal call to a constructor decorated with @PostConstruct and it started working fine. I've updated the original post to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: I also changed the logout to a servlet and that seemed to work.  Even though I was doing basic same thing with a jsf action method.